# Is there a way to use my file system as a cache?

Tags: java, caching, data-structures, jsoup

I’m am taking a data structures course and am developing a project in java. The project is pretty much complete except for one aspect, implementation of a cache. My professor has been very vague as he is and should be with everything on how to implement this. The only hint he had given is that our operating system has its own file system which in and of itself is a map, and we can use it as a way to create a cache. I will paste the assignment details below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Almost forgot. My OS is windows 10

Requirements

This assignment asks you to create a web page categorization program.
The program reads 20 (or more) web pages. The urls for some of these web pages can be maintained in a control file that is read when the program starts. The others should be links from these pages. (Wikipedia is recommended source.) For each page, the program maintains frequencies of words along with any other related information that you choose.
The user can enter any other URL, and the program reports which other known page is most closely related, using a similarity metric of your choosing.
The implementation restrictions are:

Create a cache based on a custom hash table class you implement to keep track of pages that have not been modified since accessed; keep them in local files.
Use library collections or your own data structures for all other data stores. Read through the Collections tutorial.
Establish a similarity metric. This must be in part based on word-frequencies, but may include other attributes. If you follow the recommended approach of hash-based TF-IDF, create a hash table storing these.
A GUI allows a user to indicate one entity, and displays one or more similar ones.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: I’m not looking for any code. I’m just looking for a nudge in the right direction

Comment: Hint: he is saying to keep pages that you have read previously in the file system.  So you could encode the URL so that it is a valid file name.  Or you could generate your own unique identifier for each URL, use the identifier as a file name, and store the association between the URL and identifier in your data structure.

Comment: "The only hint he had given is that our operating system has its own file system which in and of itself is a map ..." What he means (I think) is that a file system is a mapping from pathnames to file system objects (files, directories, etcetera).

Comment: So are you saying after I do a doc connect I could strip all the punctuation from the url and save it as a file in a directory on my desktop?

Comment: I’m 37 years old with a full time job. I’m not 19 living in a dorm with all the time in the world. It’s hard to solve problem solve when you don’t fully understand  the problem. I was under the impression that this site could be used as a resource to help solve problems. Part of problem solving is asking questions and obtaining knowledge. If you noticed I didn’t ask you for a line of code or a solution.

Comment: I am trying figure out exactly what he wants and was posting on this site in hopes that someone could help me conceptualize exactly what he is asking for. I do have a few more questions, but if you don’t want to help me that’s fine hopefully someone else sees this and can shed some more light. Thanks for the help you have given me up to this point. Have a nice night

Comment: " I was under the impression that this site could be used as a resource to help solve problems."  Actually, that's not correct.  This is a Question and Answer site, not a problem solving site, or a site to deal with the deficiencies in the way that one is being taught.